# Using ModelBuilder to create different layers by selecting all attributes that intersect each grid index cells

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, vector-grid

I have a large grid index layer and point layer. I want to use ModelBuilder that will select each cell in the grid index layer, then perform a select by location to select all the points within each cell. I then want to export this data into its own layer. I want the model to run through each cell automatically giving me multiple layer files.

How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried?  What does your model so far look like?

Answer (score 1):

ArcToolbox -> Analysis Tools -> Extract -> Split

You can add this tool to a model or run it directly from ArcToolbox.

It splits an existing feature class using a Polygon feature class to spatially define the groups to create.

The groups will be created in a target dataset and given a name based on a selected attribute of the dividing polygon feature class.

[image]